# How can I use objects/classes from another namespace in C# (visual studio 2013)

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a few differenet namespaces in my solution and I want to use an object called "Doctor" from namespece BL_Backend inside another namespace called DAL. I've tried adding a Refference to DAL (a refference for BL_Backend), and then adding "using BL_Backend;" but it wouldn't work. still classes such as Doctor won't appear as known ones inside namespace DAL.

```
namespace BL_Backend
{
…
namespace DAL
{
    …
    //Here create object as "Doctor" for BL_Backend class
}
}
```

For example,
when i call a constructor of a doctor from DAL it says this constructor does not exists but when i write the exact same command at namespace bl_backend it works fine.

thanks alot!

Comment: It sounds like you're using the word `namespace` when in fact you're probably referring to `assembly`s. Assemblies and namespaces are two *separate* concepts in .NET. A single assembly (something you can reference) may contain multiple types in multiple namespaces. And the types within a single namespace may come from multiple assemblies. That's why, in all the MSDN documentation for framework types, you'll find both the namespace *and* the assembly listed.

Comment: This is very wrong practice to use namespace within another namespace.. you should instead use namespace1.namespace2 if you want to have a standard order of namespaces within your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Doctor` is declared as [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in `BL_Backend` assembly. Note - if class does not have `public` [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then by default it will be `internal`:

```
namespace BL_Backend
{
    class Doctor // this class is internal
    {

    }
}
```

Internal classes are visible only within assembly they are defined (well, there is attribute [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows other assemblies to see internal classes, but without applying this attribute, class is not visible to other assemblies).

Comment: didn't know classes need to be public also, thanks alot - it works !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class `Doctor` from an assembly `BL_Backend` in a `DAL` you must add a reference in `DAL` to the `BL_Backend` not vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Classes without a modifier are internal by default, so ensure that your modifier is public.
As a second option pay attention to the build order - its not a problem in VS12+ anymore, but in further versions it was.